# docker-proxy keeps port open making it impossible to start a service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I perform docker-compose down  and I have:

```
$ docker-compose ps
Name   Command   State   Ports
------------------------------
```

But when I do docker-compose up -d, I get

`ERROR: for php  Cannot start service php: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint project_php_1 (1a97183b3dad2157994251af0ead734e6750d95a3c71540d95f4c32c487d0830): Bind for 127.0.0.1:9000 failed: port is already allocated`

Netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          24211      1643/docker-proxy
```

ps:

```
$ sudo ps auxwwwt | grep docker-proxy
root     18924  0.0  0.1 1152904 3132 ?        Sl   11:56   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 127.0.0.1 -host-port 9000 -container-ip 172.23.0.2 -container-port 9000
root     19233  0.0  0.1 1152904 3220 ?        Sl   11:56   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 54321 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 5432
root     19241  0.0  0.1 1079172 4032 ?        Sl   11:56   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 54321 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 5432\
```

I stop and start the docker service, but the docker-proxy keeps coming up. What can I do to stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have containers running from outside this compose setup. Use `docker ps` to list all running containers and stop them. Afterwards, to be sure, use `docker network prune` to remove orphaned networks.

After that your compose setup should start normally.